# Flutter | PurchaseDetails.billingClientPurchase was removed at in_app_purchase than 0.60

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

There is one significant regression in the in_app_purchase 0.6.0

In 0.5.2, PurchaseDetails contained the billingClientPurchase field with additional Android related information.

The billingClientPurchase contained one very important piece of information: signature.

This signature is required to locally verify a purchase. In 0.6.0, one can only find PurchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData (another important piece of data), but no signature can be received.

Please could you add the signature as well?

```
  Future<bool> _verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async
  {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      try {
        final body = json.encode({
          'signature': purchaseDetails.billingClientPurchase.signature, // Compile error
          'receipt': purchaseDetails.verificationData.localVerificationData,
        })

        await http.post(RECEIPT_VERIFICATION_ENDPOINT_FOR_ANDROID, body: body);

        purchaseDetails.billingClientPurchase.isAutoRenewing; // Compile error
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```